# How to make Outlook show inline attachments?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, compatibility

I send an email from Mac Mail (Mail 8.2 on 10.10.4), as either RTF or Plain Text, with embedded inline pictures & files, as this example…

[image]

It arrives at Outlook mail with everything after the first picture moved out to separate attachments.

[image]

Is there anything I can do at either send or receive to stop Outlook doing this? It really should not be making it's own unilateral decisions on formatting.
I believe this is Office 2010. Though overall I'm going to have less control over which version of Office is at the receiving end, has this improved with later versions of Office (anything I can do to persuade people to be on something made this decade, perhaps) ?

I've read that sending as HTML might prevent it, but I don't have that option from Mail, plain or rtf only.